# C calloc cannot convert from void* to double*

Tags: c++

I am trying to mix **C** with **C++** code. For memory allocation, I am using the calloc function like

```
states = calloc(nStates + 1, sizeof(double));
derivatives = calloc(nStates + 1, sizeof(double));
```

but I am getting an error saying: `cannot convert from void* to double*`.

For any ideas I would be appreciated.

Comment: C or C++ pick one language please.

Comment: in C++ you have to cast the pointer: `derivatives = static_cast<double *>(calloc(nStates + 1, sizeof(double)));`

Comment: C & C++ are different languages. This is one of their difference.

Comment: `states = static_cast<double *>(calloc(...))`

Comment: If you're programming in C++ (which I'm guessing you do because of the errors), please use only `new` (or `new[]`). The pointers you get will be usable when calling C functions. ***Unless*** the C functions will free the memory, then *and only then* should you use the C `malloc` (or related) functions.

Comment: You cannot mix C and C++ code in the same source code! You apparently use a C++ compiler. C and C++ are **different** languages. Identical syntax does not mean identical semantics!

Comment: If your'e gonna use a C++ compiler, program in C++ `std::vector<double> states (nStates + 1, 0.0)`. Type safe and robust.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there is no implicit conversion from the type `void *` to any other pointer type. You have to use an explicit casting of the returned pointer of type `void *`..

For example

```
states = ( double * )calloc(nStates + 1, sizeof(double));
```

Comment: If you want use a C++-style cast you could also use `states = reinterpret_cast<double *> (calloc(nStates + 1, sizeof(double)));`.

Comment: Thank you.I  have another part like :  dymBasicD = (double *) (calloc(1, sizeof(struct BasicDDymosimStruct)));It's giving an error saying: cannot convert from 'double*' to'basicDymosimStruct*'.

Comment: @venkatreddy You have to cast to the type of the pointer for which the memory is allocated.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am not quite sure about the pointer type.ifdef  SOURCE_CODE_EXPORTED
 /* Defining required globals */
 static struct BasicIDymosimStruct*basicI = 0;
 static struct BasicDDymosimStruct*basicD = 0;
 struct BasicIDymosimStruct*getBasicIDymosimStruct() {
  return basicI;
 }
 struct BasicDDymosimStruct*getBasicDDymosimStruct() {
  return basicD;
 }
 void setBasicStruct(double*d, int*i) {
  basicI = (struct BasicIDymosimStruct*)(i);
  basicD = (struct BasicDDymosimStruct*)(d);
 }
This is the definition.

Comment: @venkatreddy In this case to provide the code compilation in C and C++ you should define a typedef for the pointer depending on the macro name and use it in the casting expression.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged C++, I'll just go ahead and suggest you use `std::vector` instead. As it is, your code has several problems:

1. The cast, obviously. It's a sign of trying to go around the type system, which is rarely a good thing.
2. You manage dynamically allocated memory yourself. Which is error prone, and the reason C++ was pretty much created around the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) programming idiom. You have the power of C++, so use it.
3. There is no guarantee a 0-bit pattern is the representation of `0.0`.

All those problems go away, and your code becomes easier to maintain, when you replace raw pointers and `calloc` with a simple:

```
std::vector<double> states (nStates + 1, 0.0);
std::vector<double> derivatives (nStates + 1, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That conversion is legal C but illegal in C++. You'll need to cast it manually.